# Adding search root path for Ruby require (GCC -L equivalent)

Tags: ruby, search, directory, require

I used `-L` on GCC to specify additional search root directory. And then GCC will search the directory in addition to default system search directory.

I think Ruby `require` only searches system's gem installation directory. And when I used `ruby -I <path>` it seems looks for only in the specified directory, and excludes system gem installation directory.

It's simple and clean, but I want it to use system gems directory and also additional search directories. Just like GCC `-L` parameter. Is there any option to do this? Or do I have convenient alias for system gem directory which is portable over systems?

Or should I install expected gems locally to my project? I it's been expected, how can I do this?

Comment: `-I` will add the paths specified to the load path, using it shouldn’t exclude the system paths. Do you have an example of what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @matt You're right. I confirmed `-I` is working identically with GCC `-L` parameter. I don't know why I thought that's different, but I think it may because I used some wrong configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Simple to do. To add a directory to the Ruby path, do this before any requires:

```
$: << '/path/to/gem/dir'
```

Comment: Oh. Can I have some explanation about `$:`? It's very hard to search something with the letters.

Comment: @Eonil: $: is the array of paths where ruby will search for librarys

Comment: `$:` is equivalent to `$LOAD_PATH`, which is a bit less obfuscated.